# Script to count number of files in each directory

Tags: shell

I need to count the number of files on a large number of directories. Is there an easy way to do this with a shell script (using find, wc, sed, awk or similar)? Just to avoid having to write a proper script in python.

The output would be something like this:

```
$ <magic_command>
dir1  2
dir2 12
dir3  5
```

The number after the dir name would be the number of files. A plus would be able to turn counting of dot/hidden files on and off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the below one:

```
du -a | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-files-in-a-folder-510009/#post3466477

Comment: it listed files for me, too bad!

Answer (score 6):

```
find <dir> -type f | wc -l
```

*find  -type f* will list all files in the specified directory one at each line, *wc -l* count the amount of newlines seen from stdin.

Also for future reference: answers like this are a google away.

Comment: I know that answer. The question was a little bit different. Is there a simple way to put that in a loop for all directories?

Answer (score 4):

More or less what I was looking for:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "{}" `ls "{}" |wc -l`' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

try      `ls | wc` it list the file in your directory and gives list of file output to wc as input

Answer (score 3):

One way like this:

```
$ for dir in $(find . -type d  )
> do
>  echo $dir $(ls -A $dir | wc -l )
> done
```

Just remove the -A option if you do not want the hidden file count

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d | xargs ls -1 | perl -lne 'if(/^\./ || eof){print $a." ".$count;$a=$_;$count=-1}else{$count++}'
```

below is the test:

```
> find . -type d
.
./SunWS_cache
./wicked
./wicked/segvhandler
./test
./test/test2
./test/tempdir.
./signal_handlers
./signal_handlers/part2
> find . -type d | xargs ls -1 | perl -lne 'if(/^\./ || eof){print $a." ".$count;$a=$_;$count=-1}else{$count++}'

.: 79
./SunWS_cache: 4
./signal_handlers: 6
./signal_handlers/part2: 5
./test: 6
./test/tempdir.: 0
./test/test2: 0
./wicked: 4
./wicked/segvhandler: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

A **generic version** of Mehdi Karamosly's solution *to list folders of any directory without changing current directory*

```
DIR=~/test/ sh -c 'cd $DIR; du -a | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr'
```

**Explanation:**

1. Extract directory into variable
2. Start new shell
3. Change directory in that shell so that current shell's directory stays same
4. Process

Answer (score 0):

I use these functions:

```
nf()(for d;do echo $(ls -A -- "$d"|wc -l) "$d";done)
nfr()(for d;do echo $(find "$d" -mindepth 1|wc -l) "$d";done)
```

Both assume that filenames don't contain newlines.

Here's bash-only versions:

```
nf()(shopt -s nullglob dotglob;for d;do a=("$d"/*);echo "${#a[@]} $d";done)
nfr()(shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar;for d;do a=("$d"/**);echo "${#a[@]} $d";done)
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the output from the du based answer, but when I was looking at a large filesystem it was taking ages, so I put together a small ls based script which gives the same output, but much quicker:

```
for dir in `ls -1A ~/test/`;
do
  echo "$dir `ls -R1Ap ~/test/$dir | grep -Ev "[/:]|^\s*$" | wc -l`"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out copying the output of ls command in a text file and then count the number of lines in that file.

`ls $LOCATION > outText.txt; NUM_FILES=$(wc -w outText.txt); echo $NUM_FILES`

Answer (score -1):

`find -type f -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`